# .htaccess not working even though allowoverride is enabled

Tags: apache, codeigniter, ubuntu, laravel

I'm using CodeIgniter and have just installed a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu 10.10 cloud server.

Everything is working great, and I have the Apache userdir module enabled so that my home directory sits at `/home/myapp/public_html`, and I access it by going to `servername/~myapp`.

Unfortuntely, `.htaccess` rewrite does not seem to be working - it causes a 404 saying `the file /home/myapp/public_html/index.php` could not be found - a 404 error.

Mod_rewrite is enabled.

I'm aware that you need to set the `AllowOverride All` directive - I have it set in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` - yet rewrite doesn't seem to be working properly.

My `.htaccess` file simply contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|img|stylesheets|js|icons|robots\.txt|user_guide)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin dan@danmatthews.me

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride ALL
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

And finally, `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride All
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Deny from all
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I've been googling and fiddling for hours, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 25):

For what it's worth, I had a very similar problem with Ubuntu Server 11.10 and LAMP. I had to run the command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

which did the trick for me. Maybe it's the solution for you or some other people coming in here.

Comment: This also worked for me.... Using laravel with Ubuntu 10.10 having the same problem...

Comment: This issue came up for me too on ubu 12.04LTS, it worked!!, glad we have something like stackoverflow!